# UML association that is not an aggregation or composition?

Tags: java, c#, oop, uml, object-oriented-analysis

Can someone give a code example of an association UML relationship (one way arrow ->) that is neither an aggregation nor a composition?

I understand that aggregation and composition are types of associations, but I cannot think of an association  relationship that is not an aggregation or a composition.

Can the following code be just an association relationship from A->B, but not aggregation or composition under certain conditions?

```
import B;
public class A {
  private B b;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Robert Martin:

> An Association represents the ability of one instance to send a
>   message to another instance. This is typically implemented with a
>   pointer or reference instance variable, although it might also be
>   implemented as a method argument, or the creation of a local variable.

The code:

```
public class A {
  private B b;
}
```

can represent either association, aggregation or composition. It represents a mere association as long as A doesn't have a "HAS-A" relationship with B. For instance, the following could be an association, but not an aggregation or composition relationship.

```
public class Vehicle {
  private Person owner;
}
```

Comment: Owning a vehicle implies an aggregation, which is why I used "drives" in my pithy answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just by changing what your symbols represent, a Person (A) drives (b) a Car (B), without composing it or aggregating it.

Answer (score -2):

It appeared to me this morning an Eureka moment :

Association means itself plus aggregation and composition,
sometimes we see the 3 represented like this :

### Association

- aggregation
- composition

There is another kind of relationship in UML called inheritance or derivation.

So the whole hierarchie of concepts or things is :

relationship : 2 kinds            (where relationship means putting things of two or more sets in relation to each others, or even of two things of the same set...inner relationship hence the innerjoin for the thing made of two associated things in SQL)

Inheritance :   isA kind
Association :   hasA kind

Association : (kind of relationship) 
    aggregation : kind of association 
    composition : kind of association

Inheritance kind means top down specialization and bottom up generalization

where both aggregation and composition concepts have a notion of ownership embedded... Which means for a while(temporarily: case aggregation) or during the whole lifecycle (case : composition) elements of one set are or is owned, technically the other has a ref on it, by the compositor or the aggregator.
Said otherwise, with composition the composite never exist outside the context of the compositor and "dies" with it... that is the creation ref is owned by the compositor.

and there is an hidden inheritance relationship between the concepts of aggregation and composition vis à vis Association...
That is, both are a kind of association... hence the representation with indentation, parent child relationship...

But there's a term that was often misleading to me, we call relationships of the association's kind : hasA kind !

but sometimes it makes no sense. With the driver driving a car it is an association that is not of the aggregation nor the composition kind. No ownership, thats the looser kind of assocation between the 3. And in this case we can still say that the car has a driver...

But now take an association of persons. No one has any other one, it makes no sense!
Its the association itself that has refs about the associated persons... its like template tag in vue.js or <> in react (called fragment) ... Potentially, the relationship is materialized without any one of its participants knowing about it... A driver that drive a car no matter what, owner or not, is responsible...
The whole is the association and it forms a reified entity... that has refs on its participants... In legal terms it forms one single legal entity... its the archetype of a mediator while aggregation and composition are prototypes of the oberver pattern...

Why is it not written anywhere like this ? its so fuzzy...

One last word, composition is also misleading, in the spoken language a composition has not this exclusive acception, a floral composition for example... any of the constituant live independently of the others, its an association... but it could always be viewed as an aggregation where the aggregator is outside ! thats what an association is and why, precisely we can say Has a !